# Android Action Bar Design

Tags: android, android-actionbar, customization

I have to design the following for Action Bar.
can we design it without customization.

[image]

Please let me know what is the best approach to design it.

EDIT: My application will support Android ICE-cream sandwich and higher versions, so I am not using ActionBarSherlock library.

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

The action bar is a window feature that identifies the application and user location, and provides user actions and navigation modes. You should use the action bar in most activities that need to prominently present user actions or global navigation, because the action bar offers users a consistent interface across applications and the system gracefully adapts the action bar's appearance for different screen configurations

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)  Answer. It may help you.