# How to create a custom ActionBar with a background and a pattern image?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have to create an ActionBar with a background and another image on top of the background (with opacity) which displays like a pattern.
I have found the way to set the background image for my  ActionBar, by using `setBackgrounddrawable()`.

But how can I set the pattern image on top of background image?
Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: what is pattern image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A great SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android) for making a custom action bar. To set the opacity, use `View.setAlpha(float)` 0f to 1f.

Comment: yes, that link was useful. I have also created layered list with two images. one acts as background and i have set alpha for the second one to 33 and set this images as background to action bar along with custom view.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you "http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/"
,this example having types of action bars.