# display a layout on the top of action bar (Android.)

Tags: android

I have a problem and i need your help. I want to put a horizontal layout(which contains 4 views, just to set their background) on the top Of actionbar. And i don't know how to do it.
Please your help is required.
Thank you un advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: You cannot do this is in a simplest way. ActionBar is hardcoded to be displayed on the top of your app. However, you can do a workaround with the ActionBarSherlock and modify according to your needs the main layout. Even if with that, I'm really not sure this will work! Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

Hope it helps!

For more information you can look in this link:

> [How can I implement custom Action Bar with custom buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

Comment: Ok thank. I am going to try it