# Use Image instead off text on actionbar 's label

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am wondering if I could have an image label on actionbar instead of using simple text. I still want to keep the icon on the bar, but I want to enrich the label with the image. .[image: Check the action bar]

In order to be more specific I attach an image to see what I want to succeed.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of how to customize Action Bar topic, you can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can customized your actionBar using the `android:actionBarStyle`

**example:**

add this in your style xml

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/thin_ab_style</item>
```

the thin_ab_style

```
 <style name="thin_ab_style" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/drop_down_shadow_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/icon</item>
</style>
```