# NavigationDrawer custom header design

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer and stuck with few things.

- Back button when you open the navigationdrawer.
- Customizing the navigation drawer icon position.
- Is it possible to place both navigationdrawer and back button to the left of actionbar.

Here is the image of navigationdrawer i need to do.[image]

In the above image you can see how the navigationdrawer icon has some gap from left but in my case it is attached to left so i wanted to provide some margin.

Is it possible to place back button in the header of navigationdrawer.

Last but not the least, i wanted to use actionbar back which is used in opOptionsItemSelected override function

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
    case android.R.id.home:
   ...
  }
}
```

If i use this then that back button will be placed near that navigationdrawer only. So i wanted to use both navigationdrawer and this back button.

Comment: Create a custom action bar for this to achieve. Here is a link :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15519711/3747037

http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: @AlokNair i think link is to customize actionbar but i need to customize navigationdrawer.

Comment: Your question is to customise action bar and place back button and nav drawer button like in this picture, for this to achieve you would have to customise action bar. It's the best possible option

Comment: You don't need custom action bar for that, just need to customise your action bar. Change action bar icon and add padding to it. This way you can achieve without using custom action bar.