# splitActionBarWhenNarrow doesn't work right in large screen - android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have used  the splitActionBarWhenNarrow in my app to show the action bar in the bottom of the activity

```
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

with

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

the thing is , this code works right in my phone with normal screen ( normal = not very large screen )

this is how it looks like

[image]

but here this is how it looks like in a large screen that I tried in my emulator

[image]

what's wrong why the action bar is not in the bottom since I have used splitActionBarWhenNarrow ???

p.s: I'm using the support library for my fragment activity and layout

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split Action Bar when narrow **only works when there is limited space available and all action buttons don't fit in the action bar**. But since the screen size is large, there is plenty of space and all action buttons fit in action bar so there is no need to split the action bar.

Comment: so what would you suggest for making all my action buttons at the bottom of the page since large screen have a plenty of space and it will ignore my Split Action Bar ?

Comment: You can try using tabs

Comment: thanks , I found the solution using the tabHost [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710404/4020747)

Comment: I am not sure I think you can align a custom action bar at bottom. Here is the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android/15519711#15519711