# How to extend multiple Android activities

Tags: android

Say someone wants an `Activity` which both has an action bar and a preference, the first idea in mind is probably

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity, PreferenceActivity
```

But Java doesn't allow this. I know API 11+ Activities has actionbar builtin. It's just an example of wondering how to use multiple features from multiple base classes.

EDIT: Based on the feedback it seems we have to hack in this case. IMHO it could be as simple as putting all activity utilities as fields in class `Activity` and implement getter/setter to use those utilities. Well, in reality, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot extend from two classes in Java. Typically in Android to add the ActionBar to the older `PreferenceActivity` there are a couple of hacks you can do or libraries that also do the same thing. However, recently with the new AppCompat library they introduced the [Toolbar widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) which can be used to add an Actionbar to your `PreferenceActivity` in this case. For more information, checkout [this post](http://mrengineer13.com/how-to-add-an-actionbar-to-your-settingsactivity-with-appcompat-v21/) I recently wrote on how to add a Toolbar to your legacy SettingsActivity.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

- Firstly you can't extend multiple classes..java does not support multiple inheritance see   [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077394/core-java/why-not-multiple-inheritance.html)
- Secondly using action bar sherlock library  [here,](http://actionbarsherlock.com)  this gives you action bar functionality without extending the actionbaractivity plus its backwards compatiable.

Or...you can implement a  **custom action bar**  go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance.

If you want an `ActionBar` as well as something such as Preference functionality, consider using a [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)

It's not quite the same as multiple inheritance but `Fragments` allow adding extra functionality to `Activities`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of the `PreferenceActivity`, called `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` (or whatever you would like), to use an `AppCompatDelegate` to provide the `SupportActionBar` functionality. You can then subclass the new `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` for your `MyActivity` class like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity
```

For how to do this, check out [the AppCompatPreferenceActivity sample code from the Chromium project](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/7200281446186c7192cb02f54dc2b38e02d705e5/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).