# How to right to left Activity label in android ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'm new to android and I use AppCompat theme for my actionbar. I wanna to set a Label Activity at the right position of ActionBar.

Please tell me very clearly.

Regards,me... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things that you can move around and such using a custom layout, see the post here:

[How can I implement custom Action Bar with custom buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

But if you're trying to change the "up" button or menu location, you may have to fake it because those can't be changed.

Comment: I get title of ActionBar and do some change on it, like: change size, font color and... . what use setTextDirection in property list?

Comment: setTextDirection allows you to have the text display right to left (like for Arabic and Hebrew)