# How do i modify the android actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with understanding how the Action bar can be modified.

I want to change the action bar so i can have a reqular menu button on the left side and then a name in the middle, and then a button on the right.

Wanted to add picture but i have to low rep sorry. I hope that somebody can understand and help me!

Comment: I believe your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android

Comment: Thanks, this link is the best i seen so far!