# Android ActionBar Custom Design

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am a newbie in android programming, i have to design an activity exactly like the picture in the link. I am extremely confused about how to add that search view under my actionbar.

[image]

Comment: just add it normally as first item in your xml

Answer (score 0):

you need [ToolBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) .find some example and you can modify its layout because its just a ViewGroup. Then use it as ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom action bar, below will can help you to make it.

[How can I implement custom Action Bar with custom buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

then, you have to use text watcher(http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html) in search textbox and use these methods   acc. to your need:
1. afterTextChanged
2. beforeTextChanged
3. onTextChanged