# I am trying to set custom ActionBar with tab but it's showing error

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to set custom ActionBar with tab but it's showing display below error .plz check it & help me.

with out ActionBar its working proper.

Error...

```
04-26 11:25:20.615: D/AndroidRuntime(7831): Shutting down VM
04-26 11:25:20.616: W/dalvikvm(7831): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ddfd40)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     Process: com.android.zerocool.tabviewwithactonbar, PID: 7831
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.zerocool.tabviewwithactonbar/com.android.zerocool.tabviewwithactonbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at com.android.zerocool.tabviewwithactonbar.Global.setActionbar(Global.java:16)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at com.android.zerocool.tabviewwithactonbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
04-26 11:25:20.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     ... 11 more
```

second file is Global.java i making custom bar in this file

```js
public class Global {

 public static void setActionbar(Context context, ActionBar ActionBar,
   String title) {

  ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
  ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  LayoutInflater Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

  View CustomView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
  TextView TitleTextView = (TextView) CustomView
    .findViewById(R.id.title_text);
  TitleTextView.setText(title);

  ActionBar.setCustomView(CustomView);
  ActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

 }
```

MainActivity.java is here

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,
    OnClickListener {

private TabHost tHost;

ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4, iv5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Global.setActionbar(this, getActionBar(), getString(R.string.first_tab));
    initialiseTabHost();

}

public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    this.tHost.getCurrentTab();
    // this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    setSelectedTabColor();
}

private void setSelectedTabColor() {

    switch (tHost.getCurrentTab()) {
    case 0:
        // Global.setActionbar(this, getActionBar(),
        // getString(R.string.first_tab));
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_deals_hover);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_subscription);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post_deal);
        iv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_profile);
        iv5.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_setting);
        break;
    case 1:
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_deals);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_subscription_hover);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post_deal);
        iv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_profile);
        iv5.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_setting);
        break;
    case 2:
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_deals);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_subscription);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post_deal_hover);
        iv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_profile);
        iv5.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_setting);
        break;
    case 3:
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_deals);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_subscription);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post_deal);
        iv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_profile_hover);
        iv5.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_setting);
        break;
    case 4:
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_deals);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_subscription);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post_deal);
        iv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_profile);
        iv5.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_setting_hover);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

// Tabs Creation
private void initialiseTabHost() {

    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    iv4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    iv5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv5);

    iv1.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv2.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv3.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv4.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv5.setOnClickListener(this);

    tHost = getTabHost();
    tHost.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec tSpec;

    Intent ForwardIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            FirstTabActivity.class);

    tSpec = tHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("")
            .setContent(ForwardIntent);
    tHost.addTab(tSpec);

    tSpec = tHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab2")
            .setIndicator("")
            .setContent(
                    new Intent().setClass(this, SecondTabActivity.class));
    tHost.addTab(tSpec);

    tSpec = tHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab3")
            .setIndicator("")
            .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, ThirdTabActivity.class));
    tHost.addTab(tSpec);

    tSpec = tHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab4")
            .setIndicator("")
            .setContent(
                    new Intent().setClass(this, FourthTabActivity.class));
    tHost.addTab(tSpec);
    iv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tSpec = tHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab5")
            .setIndicator("")
            .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, FifthTabActivity.class));
    tHost.addTab(tSpec);

    tHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    tHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_deals);
    tHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_business);
    tHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_profile);
    tHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_setting);

    tHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    setSelectedTabColor();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == iv1) {
        tHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    } else if (v == iv2) {
        tHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    } else if (v == iv3) {
        tHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    } else if (v == iv4) {
        tHost.setCurrentTab(3);
    } else if (v == iv5) {
        tHost.setCurrentTab(4);
    }
    setSelectedTabColor();
   }
}
```

my main activity file of XMl

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_Home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_home" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_Chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_chat" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_Post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_post_hover" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_Alert"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_alert" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_More"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_more" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="none"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and cutome action bar is bellow...

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/app_color" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/title_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:text="this is textview"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should make a variable of ActionBar and perform methods on that...  ActionBar ab=getActionBar();     ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); etc

Comment: @Prakhar... not there is not any fault

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in inflating custom layout, Refer to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15519711/1401138)
post to inflate custom layout.

Comment: there is nothing problem in it.

Comment: Try to debug you code, you're getting null in setActionBar() method for some parameter, which is causing problem.