# how to make custom actionbartoggle button in android?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Q: how to make custom actionbartoggle button in android?
I want to make custom actionbartoggle button which hamburger button shown at right top in actionbar.

I want to resize it and change color through programmatically, not in xml. I need to make custom toggle button.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android

Comment: i need to change size of hamburger toggle button, not all other things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">64dp</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">64dp</item>
</style>
```

mdpi - 32 dp = 32 px

hdpi - 32 dp * 1.5 = 48 px

xxhdpi - 32 dp * 2 = 64 px

note: changes the size of the entire Action Bar and all its contents, not just the icon though.

you can change color using

`<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>`

inside theme

[image]

images for 32 dp and 64 dp
[image]

Comment: it doesn't work, it change only action bar size, not toggle hamburger button size.

Comment: should work ..works for me.. check your theme  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" or another one

Comment: I have found it, I made custom theme for actionbartoggle.  I set attributes in it and it works. Thanks