# Kind of android menu with border-bottom when selected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm new in this android world...I would like to have this menu (I don't think if I can call it like that):

Image:

[image]

It has "Speed Dial", "Recents", etc. When one of them is selected, it got a border-bottom. What is the easiest way to get this system?

Comment: It is called a tab pager.https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: `TabLayout` is the widget you want

Comment: Also try ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

- The menu bar is called ActionBar and you have to custom make it. (Google it).(It's like normal layout! Just horizontal ALWAYS, instead of vertical)
- The layout is called **Tab Layout**. It's pretty messy and easy at the same time depending on how you write codes!
- When the user hit the keypad button at the bottom, the menu bar/action-bar disappear. use the following code to achieve that

  ```
  getActionbar().hide();
  getActionbar().show();
  ```

The following tutorials would be helpful

- [Android Hive - Material Design Working With Tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)
- [CodePath's Cliffnote over TabLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout)
- [Design Custom Actionbar](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)
- [Implement Custom Actionbar with Custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

Cheers! Happy Coding!