# Using RTL direction in closeButton of android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, widget, searchview

I'm trying to change direction of SearchView in toolbar, and this is my try

**layout.xml**

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

**menu.xml**

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_hint"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_icon"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

**Java code:**

```
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem));

        mSearchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));

        mSearchView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        mSearchView.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);    
        mSearchView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);

        mSearchView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        mSearchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
```

[image: SearchView in actionBar]
[image: Wrong position of closeButton]

And this is the result, I success added the SearchView to toolbar and is RTL now. But the issue is position of "X" (closeButton) is wrong, the position must be at left.

Comment: You can use custom layout for toolbar. [This may helpful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android)

Comment: @KaushalideSilva my issue is in SearchView not in the toolbar

Answer (score 3):

add this for change x direction:

```
    View xIcon = ((ViewGroup) mSearchView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2);
    xIcon.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 1):

To Support `Rtl` in your App. you have to set `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your manifest.xml.

**And Most Important point keep in Mind**

Change all of your app's `"Left/Right"` layout properties to `Start/End`.

In you case you are setting.

```
mSearchView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

so change it to

```
mSearchView.setGravity(Gravity.END);
```

and also change here this

```
mSearchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
```

to

```
 mSearchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.END));
```

Comment: I've already add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to my manifest.xml, and I just replace `Gravity.RIGHT` to `Gravity.END`. But the same issue with x button position

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to move closeButton to right in RTL locales:

```
  private static void handleCloseButtonRtlIssue(SearchView searchView) {
        ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2)).getChildAt(1).setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that when you change `layoutDirection` to rtl, toolbar itself will become rtl. but `layoutDirection` for other layouts inside toobar will not change. and editText with close button are in a nested layout.

so you have to find parent layout and change direction for that. if you see inside SearchView layout file. you'll find that exit button is inside a layout with `search_plate` id

so in `onCreateOptionsMenu` after setup `SearchView` do this

**kotlin**

```
mSearchView.findViewById<View>(R.id.search_plate)?.let {
    it.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
}
```

**java**

```
((View) mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_plate))
    .setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
```

## Update

or you can use this kotlin extention for other rtl problem as well.

```
fun ViewGroup.rtl() {
    val stack = Stack<View>()
    stack.add(this)
    while (stack.isNotEmpty()) {
        stack.pop().apply {
            layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
            textDirection = View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL
            (this as? ViewGroup)?.children?.forEach { stack.add(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

use it like this

```
view.rtl() //and view become rtl :)
```