# Hiding elevation of AppBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I am trying to simulate a large AppBar that is adding some extra layout to it.

For this, I place a layout just below the AppBar and assign the same color to it, but I get the elevation shadow as you can see in this picture:

[image]

I tried to configure a 4dp elevation for my layout (I tried with 8dp also) to avoid the shadow, but it doesnt dissappear.

How can I make that shadow go to simulate a big AppBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setElevation(0f);
```

Or You can make Your own view and use it as action bar like in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15519711/5343907

Answer (score 2):

in the xml file for your layout if you adding AppBarLayout tag you can define elevation and setting it to 0dp

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:elevation="0dp"></android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```