# Android Creating Custom Action Bar 3 Items

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android and i need a action bar which have a img button in left , tile in center and a Img button in right.

**This is how i want my action bar**

[image]

Comment: Check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15519711/2919483 , it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

You're going to have to learn the basics of how to create a layout in Android. The one you want could be a linear layout, constraint or relative layout. Things shouldn't be nested so the performance implications of which one you choose won't be a big factor. There are tons of tutorials out there if you google any of those or any android tutorials.