# Add icon at right end of the Actionbar in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When I do the following

```
ActionBar  actBar = getSupportActionBar();
actBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actBar.setIcon(R.drawable.noconnection);
```

The icon is left of Title.
I like to have at right end of the bar at "Here" text position.
How can I do in Android?
[image]

Comment: Use an [options menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android

Comment: Use Options Menu.
This video explains in great detail: https://youtu.be/EOkHViRwRds

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to add icon not button on action bar so mark menu option as disabled by setting `android:enabled="false"` and show it always by setting `android:showAsAction="always"`